# Combine records when using CASE

Tags: oracle11g

I want see all record in 1 row instead of 2 rows for I.ITEMNUM = '505611'. Column "D.RESTYPE" can either be APSOFT or APHARD. Hence the Case expression with the SUM function. However, my output appears in 2 rows because there is a qty of 1 classified as 'APSOFT' and a qty 43 classified as 'APHARD'. Please your prompt response is highly appreciated. FYI, this is in ORACLE.

```
SELECT   i.itemnum,
         CASE WHEN d.restype = 'APSOFT' THEN SUM (NVL (d.reservedqty, 0)) END
            AS "ALLOCATED",
         CASE WHEN d.restype = 'APHARD' THEN SUM (NVL (d.reservedqty, 0)) END
            AS "RESERVE"
FROM     mxrads.inventory n
         LEFT OUTER JOIN mxrads.item i ON i.itemnum = n.itemnum
         LEFT OUTER JOIN mscrads.invreserve d
            ON n.itemnum = d.itemnum AND n.location = d.location
WHERE        n.siteid <> 'MS'
         AND n.location = '&WHSE'
         AND n.status = 'ACTIVE'
         AND n.itemnum = '505611'
GROUP BY i.itemnum, d.restype
```

Comment: I can barely understand what you're asking. It would help tremendously if you simplified your code to highlight the problem more clearly.

Comment: Certainly Anthony. The problem is in case expression below from the select statement. I want the output to show both "Allocated" & "Reserve" in  1 row for I.itemnum = 505611 instead of 2 rows.                                        CASE 
    WHEN D.RESTYPE = 'APSOFT' THEN SUM(NVL(D.RESERVEDQTY,0))
    END AS "ALLOCATED",
CASE    
    WHEN D.RESTYPE = 'APHARD' THEN SUM(NVL(D.RESERVEDQTY,0))
    END AS "RESERVE",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `case` needs to be inside the sum rather than outside of it. Once you've done this, you'll be able to remove `d.restype` from the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
     NVL (
        SUM (
           CASE WHEN d.restype = 'APSOFT' THEN d.reservedqty ELSE NULL END),
        0)
        AS "ALLOCATED",
     NVL (
        SUM (
           CASE WHEN d.restype = 'APHARD' THEN d.reservedqty ELSE NULL END),
        0)
        AS "RESERVE",
```

When you put the case on the outside, it takes the sum of `d.reservedqty`, then displays it based on the value in `d.retype`. By reversing this, we're saying "sum only those values of `d.reservedqty` where the corresponding value of `d.restype` is the specified value".

Comment: @ Allan, thank you so much. it worked just as you stated. Thank you once more.